# How to access workspace state from VS Code commands?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm new to VS Code extension building and ran into a problem. I'm having trouble accessing objects I create and store in the [workspaceState](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ExtensionContext) property in ExtensionContext.

```
export async function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    // Some code

    const linksToDisplay = await initalizeLinks(context.workspaceState); // Initializes and saves all objects 

    // Some other code

    let visualizer = vscode.commands.registerCommand('codePlumber.visualize', displayLinksCommand);

    context.subscriptions.push(visualizer);
}

function displayLinksCommand() {
    // How can I access workspace state here?
}
```

Basically I'm creating objects at Launch time for my extension and then I want my commands to interact with those created objects.

I've tried passing context.workspaceState into the registerCommand function as an argument like

```
let visualizer = vscode.commands.registerCommand('codePlumber.visualize', displayLinksCommand, context.workspaceState);
```

but that didn't work.

Here are a couple of questions I have:

Is there a way to access workspaceState from my commands? If so, what does that code look like?

Is my approach to saving objects in ExtensionContext wrong? If so, are there other alternatives I could be using?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge the extension context is only available in the `activate` method, but you can use closures and use the context there. Here's an example:

```
context.subscriptions.push(commands.registerCommand("codePlumber.visualize",
        () => {
            // use the context here.
        }),
    );
```